# Remove FS from file in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file in NOTEPAD that has FS highlighted in black..like the way CR gets highlighted to represent \r. I need to get rid of those FS . But I do not know what its extended equivalent is. When I copy and paste it in the find field, and click Count, I get an accurate count of all of them. However I am unable to eliminate them. I have tried copying one, pasting it on the find field of the find and replace and leaving the replace field blank. But that does not work. They still remain in the document. Does anyone know how I can possibly get rid of them. They are over 9000 of them so cutting and pasting is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying those FS symbols and replacing them with a real word like "GET RID OF THIS". Then I replaced the "GET RID OF THIS" with nothing and those pesky FS symbols were gone !!

Answer (score 1):

The character visualised as FS has the ascii code 28, you can enter it by pressing 028 while holding ALT. In order to match it you would open the replace dialog,

1. select **regular expression** in the lower left,
2. leave **replace with** empty
3. Enter one of the following options into **Find what**:

   - `\x1c`, (`\x` needs the character in hexadecimal and 28 is 1c in hexadecimal)
   - `\N{IS4}`, (`\N` searches for a named character and 28 has the name IS4, see [the list of possible names and hexcodes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/collating_names/posix_symbolic_names.html))
4. press **Replace all**

Comment: Select "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)" option under Search Mode and find in the latest notepad++ version.